# How to plot using matplotlib and cartopy with lat lon values only

Tags: python, matplotlib, latitude-longitude, python-xarray, cartopy

I have LIS (Lightning Imaging Sensor, on board of International Space station) dataset of lightning flashes, it contains latitude and longitude. How to make a spatial plot using contourf with those latitude and longitude values?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

fname='/media/lightning_lis/ISS_LIS_SC_V1.0_20190227_FIN_1224*.nc' 
ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname,parallel=True)

lat =ds.lightning_flash_lat
lon =ds.lightning_flash_lon
```

> lat

> Out[60]:  <xarray.DataArray 'lightning_flash_lat' (flash_dim:
> 319)>
> dask.array<open_dataset-754ff8774f72e93b1fa4f9a424e89815lightning_flash_lat,
> shape=(319,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(319,),
> chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
>
> lon
>
> Out[61]:  <xarray.DataArray 'lightning_flash_lon' (flash_dim: 319)>
> dask.array<open_dataset-754ff8774f72e93b1fa4f9a424e89815lightning_flash_lon,
> shape=(319,), dtype=float32, chunksize=(319,),
> chunktype=numpy.ndarray>

```
crs = proj=ccrs.PlateCarree()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 12))

cmap=plt.cm.gist_ncar_r

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection=crs)
ax.contourf(lon,lat,cmap=cmap)
ax.coastlines('10m', lw=.1)
ax.set_extent([60, 100,5, 36])
ax.set_xticks([65,70,75,80,85,90,95])
ax.set_yticks([5,10,15,20,25,30,35])
ax.grid(linewidth=1, color='black', alpha=0.4, linestyle='--')
plt.savefig('lis_lightning_v2.png', dpi=550,bbox_inches='tight')
plt.show()
```

How to plot it using contourf spatially without a z (data)?

Comment: it seems like you have a list of points, and you want to bin them into a grid and essentially create a contour plot based on their frequency. check out [`numpy.histogram2d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html) - this will help you rasterize your data, then you can use the bin edges and counts as the x, y, and z data for your contour plot

Comment: if you don't need a contour plot specifically but would be fine with a pcolormesh or a hex bin plot, you can use [`plt.hist2d`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d.html) or [`plt.hexbin`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html)